# RegEx replacing numbers greater than variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the string:
"selection1 selection2 selection3 selection4"

I am looking to remove all words that end in a number greater than a variable. For instance:

```
let str = "selection1 selection2 selection3 selection4";
let x = 2;
let regExp = RegExp(...);
let filtered = str.replace(regExp , ""); // should equal "selection1 selection2"
```

I came up with the following expression which selects all words that end in numbers greater than 29:

```
/(selection[3-9][0-9]|[1-9]\d{3}\d*)/gi
```

The result from this regEx on the string "selection1 selection 40" is [selection40]

I feel that I'm part of the way there.

Given that I'm dealing with single and double digit numbers and am looking to incorporate a variable, what regEx could help me alter this string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.replace` with a callback:

```js
let str = "selection5 selection1 selection2 selection3 selection4";
let x = 2;
let regex = /\s*\b\w+?(\d+)\b/g;
let m;

let repl = str.replace(regex, function($0, $1) {
  return ($1 > x ? "" : $0);
}).trim();

console.log( repl );
```

Regex `/\b\w+?(\d+)\b/g` matches all the words ending with 1+ digits and captures digits in capture group #1 which we use inside the callback function to compare against variable `x`.

Comment: Great answer! One improvement is to replace the multiple spaces with only one space and remove the extra space(s) at the end. Something like: `repl.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()`.

Comment: Works for me! It performs very well. Also, @Khalid, thanks for the trim!

Comment: @afriedman111 My pleasure. Please note that you will need the `replace()` in the following case `let str = "selection1 selection20 selection2 selection3";`

Comment: Please note that I have taken care of space removal in above code.

Answer (score 0):

**You can split by whitespace, then capture the group [using Regex](https://regex101.com/r/IvSTuw/1) which gets the only the numeric part and filter it accordingly.**

```js
const str = "selection1 selection2 selection3 selection4";
const threshold = 2;

const pattern = /selection(\d+)/

const result = str
  .split(' ')
  .filter(x => Number(x.match(pattern)[1]) <= threshold)
  .join(' ');
  
console.log(result);
```